# Laravel Cashier Invoice Date Issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier, stripe-payments

I am using Laravel 5.8 with Laravel Cashier. When I try to show a list of invoices of a user, I used this code:

```
@foreach (Auth::user()->invoices() as $invoice)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $invoice->date()->toFormattedDateString() }}</td>
        <td>{{ $invoice->total() }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/user/invoice/{{ $invoice->id }}">Download</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

However, the line `$invoice->date()->toFormattedDateString()` gives an error:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (@) at position 0 (@): Unexpected character
```

It seems that the Invoice date is null. Are there other settings that I should follow? Downloading the invoice will also produce an error because of the Invoice date.

EDIT:
I edited the Laravel Invoice class (vendor\laravel\laravel\cashier\Invoice.php) to print the real date and it turns out, the invoice date is NULL.

```
/**
 * Get a Carbon date for the invoice.
 *
 * @param  \DateTimeZone|string  $timezone
 * @return \Carbon\Carbon
 */
public function date($timezone = null)
{
    echo("HERE <br />");
    var_dump($this->invoice->date);
    exit();
    $carbon = Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($this->invoice->date);

    return $timezone ? $carbon->setTimezone($timezone) : $carbon;
}
```

The `var_dump($this->invoice->date);` returns NULL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Cashier DateTime::\_\_construct(): Failed to parse time string (@) at position 0 (@):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718363/laravel-cashier-datetime-construct-failed-to-parse-time-string-at-posi)

Comment: My solution could help you. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718363/laravel-cashier-datetime-construct-failed-to-parse-time-string-at-posi

Comment: Laravel Cashier 9 solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace :

```
$this->invoice->date
```

To:

```
$this->invoice->created
```