# Laravel Cashier DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (@) at position 0 (@):

Tags: laravel, php-carbon, laravel-cashier

I have this code when displaying list of invoices, this is similar or maybe exactly the same to the ones in the official Laravel Cashier documentation. I am getting this weird `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (@) at position 0 (@): Unexpected character` error and I'm not sure what's the @ character doing in replace of a supposed to be date.

```
@foreach (Auth::user()->invoices() as $invoice)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $invoice->date()->toFormattedDateString() }}</td>
        <td>{{ $invoice->total() }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/user/invoice/{{ $invoice->id }}">Download</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Does anyone have a similar experience? I have also tried to just `var_dump` each `$invoice->date()` in the controller but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're not using the most upto date version of Laravel Cashier. In older versions, if you follow the code through, you'll see that Laravel Cashier is trying to format a property that Stripe no longer returns.

**cashier\src\Invoice.php, line 48**

`$carbon = Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($this->invoice->date);`

As per the Stripe "API Upgrade Guide", you can see on 2019-03-14, they announced the following change;

"The date property has been renamed to created." (Source: https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2019-03-14)

The latest version of Cashier has addressed this issue by checking for the existance of the `created` property first.

https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/9.0/src/Invoice.php#L48

EDIT: If you can't upgrade for whatever reason, instead of:

`$invoice->date()->toFormattedDateString()`

You can try something like:

`Carbon::createFromTimestamp($invoice->asStripeInvoice()->created)->toFormattedDateString();`

Comment: Thanks Darren. Yeah, I was using Laravel Cashier 7.0 and 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same error. The date on the label is `null`.

I was reading [Stripe's docs](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2019-03-14) and since March 14, 2019 they made some changes.

`Laravel Cashier` will stop obtaining the invoice date because Stripe will no longer provide it.

> There are a few changes to the invoice object:

- A `status_transitions` hash now contains the timestamps when an invoice
  was finalized, paid, marked uncollectible, or voided.
- The `date` property has been renamed to created.
- The `finalized_at` property has been moved into the `status_transitions` hash.

Now, how did I solve it?

1. I changed my version of Laravel Cashier by `9.3` in `composer.json` file.
2. I opened my terminal and ran `composer update`.

I hope my solution is useful for you. Regards!

Comment: would it break anything on upgrade from 7.0 to 9.3?