# Date Issue in Laravel Cashier Invoice

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I have this code to view all invoices in my page:

```
@foreach ($user->invoices() as $invoice)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $invoice->date()->toFormattedDateString() }}</td>
        <td>{{ $invoice->total() }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/invoice/{{ $invoice->id }}">Download</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

However, the line `$invoice->date()->toFormattedDateString()` gives an error:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (@) at position 0 (@): Unexpected character
```

I just followed all instructions in the Laravel Cashier (Billing) website and I am getting this error. I have tried two versions of Laravel (5.8 and 5.5) and two Laravel Cashier versions (8.0 and 7.0). All tests have the same date issue.

I have added the correct migrations fields. This is how I insert/add subscription to my database:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->newSubscription('eat', 'eat_monthly')->create($request->stripeToken);
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping out $invoice->date() to see if there would be any reason the method toFormattedDateString() would not work?

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention... $invoice->date() is NULL...

Comment: why are you trying to convert NULL to a date time string?

Comment: That's the problem, Laravel Cashier handles all the data from insert and update. This is my main issue, why is it NULL in the first place. This is the code to add a subscription
`$user->newSubscription('eat', 'eat_monthly')->create($request->stripeToken);`
but all the records created by this method have a NULL date.

Comment: Maybe try dumping out your subscription information in your controller to check that it is coming through at all before you store it in the DB - if the value is there we can work from there :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Cashier Invoice Date Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55685197/laravel-cashier-invoice-date-issue)

Answer (score 1):

instead of `{{ $invoice->date()->toFormattedDateString() }}`

Can you try `{{ $invoice->created_at->toFormattedDateString() }}` ?

Comment: Yes, this could work in the list of invoices but in the generation of invoices, I would still get an error because the $invoice->date() is NULL.

Comment: I tried this, but get a `Call to a member function toFormattedDateString() on int` error. Ended up using `Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($invoice->created)`

Answer (score 1):

Stripe has changed `date` parament to `created` works. 
Use this way:`{{ $invoice->created }}`